# How to extract the value from a url stored in a clob column

Tags: oracle, url, clob

For example if the url is "http://abcretreival.stacks.com/questi/component/getcontent?objectid=12345a2z786c1001&basecod=aiae_drp" I need the extract the value of object id

Comment: Please add some more description of what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp functions for this:

```
select regexp_substr(
    myclob,
    'object_id=([^&]*)',
    1,
    1,
    null,
    1
) object_id
from mytable
```